# ViewPager showing Scrolling issue inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

An android newbie is here :-)
I am studying CoordinatorLanyout in material designing. So I tried to implement TabLayout inside CoordinatorLanyout and it worked fine. But I implemented the RecyclerView inside one fragment for ViewPager and faced a strange scrolling issue. The list is not scrolling now. I surfed and tried lot of solutions here but nothing can fix this issue. here am is my activity_main.xm

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="10dp">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/counter_id"
            layout="@layout/counter_layout"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/pager_tab_id"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

here the frame layout for replacing the fragments. so the viewpager will take this frame container.

Am using this xml for set the viewPager layout which will use the FrameLayout in the activity_main.xml that i mentioned above

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="bodhi.electionpoll.ui.fragment.PanchayathHistoryFragment">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/content_panchayath_hisory_pager"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

next i designed a xml for RecyclerView adapter

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container_service"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:hint="Search here"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i think no need to mention related java files

after implementation of these,
the scrolling is not working

Answer (score 1):

Your structure should be like this ->

```
    <CoordinatorLayout>
        <AppBarLayout>
            <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                 <Layout/>
                 <Toolbar/>
            </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
          <TabLayout/>
        </AppBarLayout>
     <ViewPager/>
  </CoordinatorLayout>
```

i think you will understand.

Comment: i dont think so becz now my tabs are invisible

Comment: put your viewpage between the end of AppBarLayout and end of CoordinatorLayout. It should work fine. 

Also remove the NestedScrollView.

Comment: sorry if am removing nextedscrollview my other option's scroll will go.. I fixed that problem by implementing this NextedScrollView